# Progress bar without losing time in C

Tags: c

I understand how to make a progress bar in C (just print how much is done and before the print, flush the screen). But for doing that, I lose time (it takes much more time with a progress bar to solve a problem, than without a progress bar). By progress bar I mean percentage of how much already has been done. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: What is it you want to do - display a progress bar when your program is doing something but the CPU should not waste cycles in displaying the progress bar ?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use threads?

Comment: The process of updating the progress-bar should use minimal time compared to the actual processing done in the background. If it *does have* notable impact, you probably shouldn't use a progress bar since it is redundant when the evolution of the progress is almost uncatchable by human eyes.

Comment: @paulsm4's excellent suggestion would let you update the progress bar (say) once per second regardless of how long it takes for the problem to be solved. Thus, if the problem takes (say) 1 second to solve the reported progress would go to 100% on the first report but, if it takes 100 seconds to solve, the progress would be reported 100 times, with a 1% increment for each report. Incidentally, for this case I find it is useful to estimate and report the expected finishing time or the time remaining as well as the percentage completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's significantly increasing your run time then perhaps you are writing to stdout too often. For example try something like

```
for(i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    printf("\r%d",i);
```

vs

```
for(i = 0; i < 1000000; i++);
```

To improve performance you can write to the console after so many operations or after an elapsed time.

Comment: Hold on, I think I get it... wait, what?!